# maxlength not working in html form input field with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I am using bootstrap and currently created form with 5 tabs in it. I have a form field called layer time in which I have 3 input fields namely hours, minutes,seconds. I want to set the maxlength of 2 for each field.But it is not working when I specify it. Please help me out with this. Following is my code for bootstrap form.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#basic-layer-tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Basic Layer Data</b><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#basic-calcuations-tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Basic Calculations</b><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#doping-N2-tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Doping-Nitrogen</b><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#doping-Al-tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Doping-Aluminium</b><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#other-calcuations-tab" data-toggle="tab"><b>Other Calculations</b><i class="fa"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<form action="insertlayer.php" id="newlayerform" role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >

        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="basic-layer-tab">

               <div class= "panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="container-fluid">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="layer_time" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color:red">Layer Time</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="layer_time_hours" id="layer_time_hours" maxlength="2">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><b>hh</b></div>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="layer_time_minutes" id="layer_time_minutes" maxlength="2">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><b>mm</b></div>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="layer_time_minutes" id="layer_time_minutes" maxlength="2">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><b>ss</b></div>
                                    </div><!--end of input group--> 
                                </div><!--end of column class-->
                            </div>

                        </div><!--end of container-fluid-->

                    </div><!--end of panel body-->
                </div><!--end of panel default-->

            </div><!--end of tab-pane basic-layer-tab-->

</form> <!--end of form-->
```

For ease of understanding, I have just provided only information in one tab and one form field in the first tab. However there are 5 tabs in my form and each tab has many form fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not bootstrap that are causing this. `maxlength` does only apply to `<input>`'s of `type` *text*, *email*, *search*, *password*, *tel* or *url*. See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Thats why `maxlength` not works with your `<input type="number" maxlength="2">`

Proof of concept :

```js
text : <input type="text" maxlength="2">
number : <input type="number" maxlength="2">
```

here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7ba2oys7/**

Comment: But if you implement the form-control class that function not work

Comment: @NIDIARAMIREZ, what do you mean? It makes no difference if you use `form-control` or other bootstrap classes -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j941pqgv/**

Comment: maxlength on a text input isn't working for me when the string is injected with an mvvm framework (vue.js). Kinda works in Chrome, if i go to edit it and after it's too long will trigger invalid, in Edge, not at all. Both, if I edit and come below maxlength, then they won't let me go beyond it again.