# neither maxlenght or ng-maxlength seems to be working angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following input in my html file:

```
 <input name="password" 
        id="newPasswordConfirmation" 
        ng-model="newPasswordConfirmation" 
        type="number" 
        inputmode="numeric" 
        placeholder="" 
        required 
        minlength="8" 
        maxlength="8" 
        autocomplete="off" 
        ng-maxlength="8" 
        autocorrect="off" 
        autocapitalize="off" 
        style="-webkit-text-security: disc; text-security: disc;">
```

I want to limit the input to 8 algarisms, but when I type on my mobile device (android) , I can go on typing past 8 algarisms. Why is this not working and how can you make this restriction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maxlength not working in html form input field with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887540/maxlength-not-working-in-html-form-input-field-with-bootstrap)

Comment: `maxlength` does only apply to `<input>`'s of type text, email, search, password, tel or url. But you could create a directive that mimicks `maxlength` on number inputs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `maxlength` does not work with number inputs. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> **maxlength**: If the value of the type attribute is text, email, search, password,
>   tel, or url, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters
>   (in UTF-16 code units) that the user can enter. For other control
>   types, it is ignored.

Here is a small directive you can use instead :

```js
angular.module('myApp').directive('maxLength', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var maxLength = attrs.maxLength || false;
      if (maxLength) element.on('keydown keypress keyup paste propertychange', function(e) {
        if (element[0].value.length >= maxLength - 1) {
          element[0].value = element[0].value.slice(0, maxLength)
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" max-length="8">
```

Comment: I realized that changing the type to text but keeping the inputmode numeric works just as well, so maybe there is no need for the directive.

Comment: @AnaSequeira, be aware that `inputmode` is about which virtual keyboard to display, i.e it does not actually prevent the field from accepting letters. It have no effect on desktop browsers with psysical keyboards. That is, if the browser support `inputmode` at all in the first place.  `inputmode` is no longer included in specification, marked as obsolete. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kulish/5j0bdfrc/1/)

```
   <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
       <input type="text"
           ng-model="model" 
           ng-keypress="limitKeypress($event, model, 8)"
           placeholder="enter first 8 digits">
    </div>

    angular.module('App', []).controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.model = 'test'

        $scope.limitKeypress = function ($event, value, maxLength) {
            if (value != undefined && value.toString().length >= maxLength) {
                $event.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    }
    Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```